# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined misc.js:181 checkout shipping page Magento 2.3.5

Tags: knockoutjs, checkout-page, magento2.3.5, frontend-error

> I am facing below console error in our site so that some of our extension stopped
> working in checkout shipping page Magento 2.3.5

[image]

> pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_GB/mage/utils/misc.js

```
define([
        'underscore',
        'jquery',
        'FormData'
    ], function (_, $) {
        'use strict';
    
        var defaultAttributes,
            ajaxSettings,
            map;
    
        defaultAttributes = {
            method: 'post',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
        };
    
        ajaxSettings = {
            default: {
                method: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            },
            simple: {
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        };
    
        map = {
            'D': 'DDD',
            'dd': 'DD',
            'd': 'D',
            'EEEE': 'dddd',
            'EEE': 'ddd',
            'e': 'd',
            'yyyy': 'YYYY',
            'yy': 'YY',
            'y': 'YYYY',
            'a': 'A'
        };
    
        return {
    
            /**
             * Generates a unique identifier.
             *
             * @param {Number} [size=7] - Length of a resulting identifier.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            uniqueid: function (size) {
                var code = Math.random() * 25 + 65 | 0,
                    idstr = String.fromCharCode(code);
    
                size = size || 7;
    
                while (idstr.length < size) {
                    code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 42 + 48);
    
                    if (code < 58 || code > 64) {
                        idstr += String.fromCharCode(code);
                    }
                }
    
                return idstr;
            },
    
            /**
             * Limits function call.
             *
             * @param {Object} owner
             * @param {String} target
             * @param {Number} limit
             */
            limit: function (owner, target, limit) {
                var fn = owner[target];
    
                owner[target] = _.debounce(fn.bind(owner), limit);
            },
    
            /**
             * Converts mage date format to a moment.js format.
             *
             * @param {String} mageFormat
             * @returns {String}
             */
            normalizeDate: function (mageFormat) {
                var result = mageFormat;
    
                _.each(map, function (moment, mage) {
                    result = result.replace(mage, moment);
                });
    
                return result;
            },
    
            /**
             * Puts provided value in range of min and max parameters.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be located.
             * @param {Number} min - Min value.
             * @param {Number} max - Max value.
             * @returns {Number}
             */
            inRange: function (value, min, max) {
                return Math.min(Math.max(min, value), max);
            },
    
            /**
             * Serializes and sends data via POST request.
             *
             * @param {Object} options - Options object that consists of
             *      a 'url' and 'data' properties.
             * @param {Object} attrs - Attributes that will be added to virtual form.
             */
            submit: function (options, attrs) {
                var form        = document.createElement('form'),
                    data        = this.serialize(options.data),
                    attributes  = _.extend({}, defaultAttributes, attrs || {});
    
                if (!attributes.action) {
                    attributes.action = options.url;
                }
    
                data['form_key'] = window.FORM_KEY;
    
                _.each(attributes, function (value, name) {
                    form.setAttribute(name, value);
                });
    
                data = _.map(
                    data,
                    function (value, name) {
                        return '<input type="hidden" ' +
                            'name="' + _.escape(name) + '" ' +
                            'value="' + _.escape(value) + '"' +
                            ' />';
                    }
                ).join('');
    
                form.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', data);
                document.body.appendChild(form);
    
                form.submit();
            },
    
            /**
             * Serializes and sends data via AJAX POST request.
             *
             * @param {Object} options - Options object that consists of
             *      a 'url' and 'data' properties.
             * @param {Object} config
             */
            ajaxSubmit: function (options, config) {
                var t = new Date().getTime(),
                    settings;
    
                options.data['form_key'] = window.FORM_KEY;
                options.data = this.prepareFormData(options.data, config.ajaxSaveType);
                settings = _.extend({}, ajaxSettings[config.ajaxSaveType], options || {});
    
                if (!config.ignoreProcessEvents) {
                    $('body').trigger('processStart');
                }
    
                return $.ajax(settings)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (config.response) {
                            data.t = t;
                            config.response.data(data);
                            config.response.status(undefined);
                            config.response.status(!data.error);
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        config.response.status(undefined);
                        config.response.status(false);
                        config.response.data({
                            error: true,
                            messages: 'Something went wrong.',
                            t: t
                        });
                    })
                    .always(function () {
                        if (!config.ignoreProcessEvents) {
                            $('body').trigger('processStop');
                        }
                    });
            },
    
            /**
             * Creates FormData object and append this data.
             *
             * @param {Object} data
             * @param {String} type
             * @returns {FormData}
             */
            prepareFormData: function (data, type) {
                var formData;
    
                if (type === 'default') {
                    formData = new FormData();
                    _.each(this.serialize(data), function (val, name) {
                        formData.append(name, val);
                    });
                } else if (type === 'simple') {
                    formData = this.serialize(data);
                }
    
                return formData;
            },
    
            /**
             * Filters data object. Finds properties with suffix
             * and sets their values to properties with the same name without suffix.
             *
             * @param {Object} data - The data object that should be filtered
             * @param {String} suffix - The string by which data object should be filtered
             * @param {String} separator - The string that is separator between property and suffix
             *
             * @returns {Object} Filtered data object
             */
            filterFormData: function (data, suffix, separator) {
                data = data || {};
                suffix = suffix || 'prepared-for-send';
                separator = separator || '-';
    
                _.each(data, function (value, key) {
                    if (_.isObject(value) && !value.length) {
                        this.filterFormData(value, suffix, separator);
                    } else if (_.isString(key) && ~key.indexOf(suffix)) {
                        data[key.split(separator)[0]] = value;
                        delete data[key];
                    }
                }, this);
    
                return data;
            },
    
            /**
             * Replaces symbol codes with their unescaped counterparts.
             *
             * @param {String} data
             *
             * @returns {String}
             */
            unescape: function (data) {
                var unescaped = _.unescape(data),
                    mapCharacters = {
                        '&#039;': '\''
                    };
    
                _.each(mapCharacters, function (value, key) {
                    unescaped = unescaped.replace(key, value);
                });
    
                return unescaped;
            },
    
            /**
             * Converts PHP IntlFormatter format to moment format.
             *
             * @param {String} format - PHP format
             * @returns {String} - moment compatible formatting
             */
            convertToMomentFormat: function (format) {
                var newFormat;
    
                newFormat = format.replace(/yyyy|yy|y/, 'YYYY'); // replace the year
                newFormat = newFormat.replace(/dd|d/g, 'DD'); // replace the date
    
                return newFormat;
            },
    
            /**
             * Get Url Parameters.
             *
             * @param {String} url - Url string
             * @returns {Object}
             */
            getUrlParameters: function (url) {
                var params = {},
                    queries = url.split('?'),
                    temp,
                    i,
                    l;
    
                if (!queries[1]) {
                    return params;
                }
    
                queries = queries[1].split('&');
    
                for (i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++) {
                    temp = queries[i].split('=');
    
                    if (temp[1]) {
                        params[temp[0]] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
                    } else {
                        params[temp[0]] = '';
                    }
                }
    
                return params;
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is related to the time line in the fail statement,

```
config.response.data({
                            error: true,
                            messages: 'Something went wrong.',
                            t: t
                        });
```

you might want initially hard-code `t` to a valid date just so that you remove any suspicion about this t variable and possible problem of casting, parsing.. Once it does work, you will be left with an issue that is about syntax, or parsing of the data

Comment: Whats the solution for it?

Comment: In the end, this code can’t be changed as it is a core js file. This error happens because a checkout error has occurred. To track it, it is likely a php error that will have some logs either in your web server logs or Magento logs depending on your setup